# Mouse scroll wheel speed far too sensitive

Tags: xorg, mouse, openbox, crunchbang, xinput

In my Crunchbang installation with X11, openbox, my wireless usb mouse is listed at both `/dev/psaux` and `/dev/input/mouse0`. It's working fine apart from the scroll wheel, which although active, is far too sensitive.

I'm thinking maybe the kernel is raising double the scroll events that it should be? Not sure what to check out even if this is the case?

I tried adjusting sensitivity via `lxinput` but it affected everything on the mouse apart from the actual scrollwheel.

xinput list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                              id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

doing

- `xinput test 9` results in expected mouse motion events (but nothing for button clicks/scrollwheel)
- `xinput test 10` results in `unknown class` with no events fired.

Comment: You can see what events X11 is getting by using `xinput`. In a terminal, do an `xinput list` to find the device id, then `xinput test «device-id»` to see all the events. (Control-C it to stop)

Comment: See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/619403

Comment: that bug refers to acceleration, the constant speed with mine is too fast. See updated xinput

Comment: @rutherford have you tried debugging it with `xev` ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Microsoft mouse, try [resetmsmice](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice), which will fix this problem, without having to unplug and replug the mouse receiver.
Many thanks to the author Paul F Richards, also the [Ubuntu launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/971321)

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase Scrolling Distance to 3, 3, 3

```
xinput --set-prop 10 274 3, 3, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

A script I wrote to cure 'jumpy mouse' -- disable_scroll

```
#!/bin/bash

id=$(xinput --list --id-only 'Logitech USB RECEIVER')
#usually "8" but sometimes "10" 

# so there are 24 different buttons possible (!)
# This will disable all the extra buttons
# use only the right, left and middle click.

/usr/bin/xinput set-button-map "${id}" \
1 2 3 0 0 0 \
0 0 0 0 0 0 \
0 0 0 0 0 0 \
0 0 0 0 0 0 
# end
```

even if you want scrolling disabling the extra button signals
may help eliminate stray interrupts. I found additionally that using a USB extension cable to get the usb radio receiver away from the chassis improves the signal/noise ratio and the mousing is more responsive and smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with name `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/71-mouse-local.hwdb` with something like this

```
# My mouse settings
mouse:usb:v093ap2510:*
   # MOUSE_DPI=600
   MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE=10
```

This will target a mouse with usb id `093a:2510` or (v)093a(p)2510.

For more info and examples look at the file `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/70-mouse.hwdb`.

To apply the changes do

```
sudo systemd-hwdb update
sudo udevadm trigger /dev/input/eventXX
sudo udevadm info /sys/class/input/eventXX
```

get the event number from xinput. The above must be done only once.

Comment: I have written a more detailed explaination (in Greek so google translate) here: https://linux-user.gr/t/pontiki-rythmish-dpi-kai-scroll-speed/995