# Does any Linux distribution support setting mouse scroll wheel sensitivity?

Tags: gnome, kde, xfce, mouse, scrolling

I have tried Ubuntu 13.04 and Linux Mint 15 and both **DO NOT HAVE** optinos for setting mouse scroll wheel sensitivity.

They had only mouse acceleration and sensitivity, but the scroll wheel speed you cannot set in these distributions.

It's frustrating, to not be able to set this thing.

Is this only a problem of Gnome distros or KDE and Xfce has the same problems too?

Comment: This has nothing to do with distributions. You need to search for xorg or xserver information - the input driver that X uses for your mouse should handle scroll speed.

Comment: @MelBoyce Where can I find these informations?

Comment: You could try an internet search engine and using something like "xorg mouse wheel scroll speed" as your search term.

Comment: you can set this for firefox in about:config i believe you can set the value for mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount but that doesn't help the rest of the distro

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Kubuntu is one of them. The mouse scroll setting is not specific to any Linux distribution, but rather supported by the desktop environment.

### Linux distribution (distro)

Kubuntu runs [KDE Plasma 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Plasma_5), beginning from [14.10 release](https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-14-10/). The mouse scroll setting can be found in KDE as early as KDE 3.5, and probably [TDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_Desktop_Environment) also, and has continued to exist in KDE Plasma 4 and newer.

- Go to **Settings > Input Devices**
- Select **Mouse - Advanced** and look for the last option "Mouse wheel scrolls by"
- Use the spinner (up-down control) to **change the value** (default: 3)
- Click **Apply** to finish.

Lubuntu runs [LXQt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lxqt), beginning from [18.10 release](https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-released/). LXQt is a relatively new desktop environment that [shares some components from KDE](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/wiki/KF5-usage-in-LXQt). The mouse scroll setting like KDE can be found in LXQt.

- Go to **Settings > Keyboard and Mouse Settings**
- Select **Mouse** and look for the option "Wheel scroll lines"
- Use the spinner (up-down control) to **change the value** (default: 3)
- Click **Close** to finish.

[image: Mouse scroll setting in KDE Plasma 5 and LXQt]

Besides Kubuntu and Lubuntu, any Linux distribution that runs KDE or LXQt will most likely have the mouse scroll setting similarly.

### Distribution-agnostic

There are distro-agnostic solutions, such as using a tool called `imwheel` or `libinput` as [suggested in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/304653), using Xorg configuration which is [often hardware-dependant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232906), and may be more.

> Is this only a problem of Gnome distros or KDE and Xfce has the same problems too?

I had used legacy KDE 3 and GNOME 2 back then, but I've come to liking Xfce because it has "sufficient" options out-of-box. And yet, Xfce doesn't have the mouse scroll setting. The reason? That is likely what has been decided by the project team, although this is concurred from my opinion.

Linux distributions that run KDE or LXQt have the mouse scroll setting, mainly because their desktop environment offers extensive options for out-of-box customization. That being said, not all distros are created equal.